# Type mismatch in key from map: expected org.apache.hadoop.io.Text, received org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable; how to correct?

Tags: hadoop, bigdata

I am experiencing the error in the title and I cannot understand how to complete this Map function in order to create the following Reduce function. Any clue? (Data devoted to the processing come from the Covid-19 .csv file which keeps track of every new case in each country, region and so on.)

The request that has been assigned to me is the following: "Give back the total number of cases per continent", so I thought to create a key-value pair composed by (key = continent, value = new_cases).

Here, I state the code in the order "Map class", "Driver Class":

```java
package ContTotCase;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.OutputCollector;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.*;
public class ContTotCasesMap extends Mapper<Text, LongWritable, Text, LongWritable> 
{
    
    public void Map(Text key, LongWritable value, OutputCollector<Text, LongWritable> output) throws IOException, InterruptedException 
    {
                
        String[] query1 = (value.toString()).split(",");
        String parseBase = query1[5];
        int parsed = Integer.parseInt(parseBase.trim());
        if(parsed > 0)
        {
            output.collect(new Text(query1[1]), new LongWritable(parsed));
        }
    }
}
```

and

```java
package ContTotCase;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;

public class ContTotCaseDriver {
    
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
         
        if (args.length != 2) {
            System.err.println("Usage: ContTotCases <InPath> <OutPath>");
            System.exit(2);
        }
 
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "ContTotCases");
        
        job.setJarByClass(ContTotCasesMap.class);
        job.setMapperClass(ContTotCasesMap.class);
        
        job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setMapOutputValueClass(LongWritable.class);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(LongWritable.class);
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
 
        System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
    }
    
}
```

Please note that I'm a newbie in Java... Thanks in advance!

Comment: The format of the data does not get passed in as: Text, LongWritable. If I remember correctly its a file reference Object as the first argument and then Text as the second argument. You would have to parse the CSV data yourself

Comment: That's a great step forward! I'll try that, thanks!